# React Native - Error while attempting to generate a private signing key

Tags: android, react-native

Hi when generating a signed apk (`cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease`) I am running into an error, does anyone know what this is or how to fix it?

```
Error: Could not delete path '/home/mohammad/exnews/android/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeReleaseResources/merged.dir/values-lv/values-lv.xml'.
```

I've tried running `sudo rm /home/mohammad/exnews/android/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeReleaseResources/merged.dir/values-lv/values-lv.xml` and then generating the apk but I'm still getting that error

Answer (score 1):

try with `cd android && ./gradlew clean && ./gradlew assembleRelease`

Answer (score 0):

You can delete all folders "build" into Android directory. I have same problem on windows.

@+